# “I got hurt” vs. “I hurt myself”

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux

How would you say each one? I know that *to hurt someone* in the emotional sense is *blesser*. Would it make sense to say:

- **Je me suis blessé**

To mean *I hurt myself* almost in a metaphorical way? As in, *I got involved with someone I shouldn’t have, and I got hurt, but I knew better, so I did it to myself.*

As opposed to:

- **Je me suis fais mal**

Which I think means *I got hurt* in a physical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say "Je me suis blessé" to a french person, he will understand that you got hurt in a physical sense. There's no doubt about it. And paradoxically, if you say "Je me suis fais **du** mal", it means that you hurt yourself in the emotional sense. In fact, "blesser" is not **only** in the emotional sense, it can be both, like "faire mal". And "faire du mal" is mainly about motion.

> - Tu m'as fait mal quand tu m'as pincé.
> - Quand tu as dit toutes ces méchancetés, ça m'a fait mal / ça m'a blessé.
> - Tu m'as fait beaucoup de mal à la fin de notre relation.
> - Je me suis fait mal / Je me suis blessé en tombant.
> - Je me suis fait du mal en tentant de la reconquérir.

Comment: That’s super interesting; gotta love the nuances, exceptions, little rules and such. :)

Comment: You can see the nuance about "blesser" [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/blesser) and the nuance about "mal" [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mal). You've got more interesting examples.